Trouble installing poliastro on VSCode
I've been trying to install poliastro on VSCode, however, when i try to install it i'm only allowed to install version 0.7.0 not the latest version.
The error message i get for more up to date versions is that the meta data is wrong or something and to use a version of pip earlier than 24.1 but when i try to change my pip version to 23.3.2 or just 24.0 i get an error and installs nothing and tells me to install the latest version of pip. Is there a way to get the most up to date version of poliastro working with my python on VSCode?

Please [edit] the question to add the entire error message as text.

the meta data error could be because of cached out-of-date information. You can try clearing the cache with the command pip cache purge first. Then use the command pip install --upgrade pip to update. Finally, try pip install poliastro==<0.12.0> in and see if that solves it. In addition, you can try installing it in venv. Use the command python -m venv myenv and then activate by .venv\Scripts\Activate. Input the command pip install poliastro==<0.12.0> to see if that resolved it.
